# 'on what amounts to' causes difficulties. What the sense of meaning whole sentence here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

What the sense of meaning whole sentence here?

> We cannot condone government involvement on what amounts to a
>   privately owned venture.

Answer (score 1):

We can be **involved in** a project or venture.

We can also be **on** a project.

**what amounts to** means "that which amounts to", that is, "that which comes very close to being" or "that which so closely resembles X that we can rightfully call it  X".

Your sentence means,  "We cannot approve of the government becoming involved in something which is really a private business venture".

If I say to you that I will not reveal a secret I know about you if you lend me your boat whenever I want to use it and let me use your penthouse suite whenever I am in town, you might say "That **amounts to** blackmail."